# How should I mock SignalR HubContext in Controller for Unit Testing?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, signalr, moq, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using SignalR in an MVC5 project. I am making calls within the controller like this:

```
private Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.IHubContext blogHubContext = Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<BlogHub>();
blogHubContext.Clients.All.addNewBlogToPage(RenderPartialViewToString("Blog", model));
```

I am attempting to unit test the actions within this controller. The unit tests were working fine until I added the SignalR functionality. Now I am trying to work out how to mock the HubContext. I have 2 possibilities.

1. I setup the hub in the constructor so I have something like the following:

   ```
   private Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.IHubContext blogHubContext;
   public BlogController(Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.IHubContext topicHub = null){
        blogHubContext = (blogHub != null) ? blogHub : Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<BlogHub>();
   }
   ```

   Then I can somehow mock the HubContext and send it through to the controller when I create it in the unit test. So far I only have this though:

   ```
   Mock<IHubContext> blogHub = new Mock<IHubContext>();
   ```

   (Note: I have simplified everything to concentrate on only the SignalR side of things. There are also repositories used in the controller etc)
2. Alternatively, I thought about creating another class to wrap the hub, and then just call functions from this to make calls to the hub. This I see as being much easier to mock for my unit tests, but not sure if it's a good idea.

Direction appreciated. Or are both acceptable ways forward? Thanks.

Comment: I prefer the 1st option since you don't need another extra layer of wrapper class which does not add any functionality.

Comment: @AD.Net Thanks. In that case, any ideas how I can go about mocking the hub for the functionality I am using. I've been struggling to work out how to do it which led me to thinking about the second option.

Comment: Are you familiar with mocking in general? Mocking a signalr hub seems like it'd be just about the same as mocking anything else.

Comment: @BenAaronson As the addNewBlogToPage function is actually a JS function which is called by SignalR, I was not sure how to go about mocking this. However, following AD.Net advice now and probably re-working things into a better structure.

Comment: @AndrewPolland, the js function will be based on your .net code, so it shouldn't really matter much for js proxy generation.

Comment: @AD.Net Still not sure how I would proceed with it. Would I do something like this Mock<IHubContext> blogHub = new Mock<IHubContext>(); blogHub.Setup(t => t.Clients.All);

Answer (score 1):

Update, please see this code, I'm basing this off the default MVC template. No need for a wrapper class.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
   private readonly IHomeHub _hub;

   public HomeController(IHomeHub hub)
   {
      _hub = hub;
   }

   public ActionResult Index()
   {
      _hub.Hello();
      return View();
   }
}

public interface IHomeHub
{
   void Hello();
}

public class HomeHub : Hub, IHomeHub
{
   public void Hello()
   {
      Clients.All.hello();
   }
}
```

for unit tests:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Index()
{
   var mockHub = new Mock<IHomeHub>();
   // Arrange
   HomeController controller = new HomeController(mockHub.Object);

   // Act
   ViewResult result = controller.Index() as ViewResult;

   // Assert
   Assert.IsNotNull(result);
   mockHub.Verify(h=>h.Hello(), Times.Once);
}
```

Comment: This seemed really good. But I can't get it to work due to only being able to call a function from the hub (within the controller) if it is static, which it can't be when implemented from an interface. So my understanding anyway.

Comment: sorry it's not clear, the method Hello is not static on the Hub class and you can call it from the controller.

Comment: Sorry, part of the problem with that was my end. Static not needed as I was thinking. However, when calling the method Hello from the controller, the client cannot be called the way you have. It produces the following error: Using a Hub instance not created by the HubPipeline is unsupported.

Comment: I've made an edit to your answer so that it does work. Hope you agree with it.

Comment: Sorry, edit was rejected. But essentially instead of Clients.All.hello(); I had to use var hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<HelloHub>();
hubContext.Clients.All.hello();

Comment: But why would you do that in the hub class itself?